# Get amount of different chars (by position) in varchar

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a varchar, say A,  column and the data, for example `abcdefghi`.

I want to create a query that when I search for the data in column A it's give me the amount of different chars (by position).

I mean, if I search for `aacdefghi` it will say 1.
If I search for `bcdefghia` it will say 9.

the length of the strings will be the same.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
My table look like:

```
A
----
abcdefghi
```

Comment: @echo_Me I dont know from where to start to do it... I provide the data in the edit..

Comment: please if someone understood explain for me. , i dont know what you want at all.

Comment: why are you hidding your data and using abcdefghjkrlakjlgdskagfksgf

Comment: This is the data... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce473/1

Comment: @Nir why second string should return 10? and not 9?

Comment: @fthiella 9, sorry :) I fix it

Answer (score 0):

I think that a script (PHP, Perl, ...) would fit better here, but if you need a MySQL solution you could start with something like this:

```
SELECT col, COUNT(*)
FROM
  tablename INNER JOIN n
  ON CHAR_LENGTH(tablename.col) >= n.n
WHERE
  SUBSTRING(tablename.col,n.n,1)!=SUBSTRING('aacdefghi', n.n, 1)
GROUP BY
  col;
```

(you will need a table n that contains numbers 1..maximum length of the string). Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8ca0/2).

Comment: Why I need the second table?

Comment: @Nir since there's no predefined function for what you are asking, i'm using a second table to simulate a FOR loop, it won't be very efficient but there's not much else you can do... please notice that my query will return no row for strings that are the same, but this behavior can be changed if you need it

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is similar to the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). You can implement it as stored routine in MySQL, see an example here:

http://kristiannissen.wordpress.com/2010/07/08/mysql-levenshtein/

You can modify this for your own needs. It is going to be very slow though, you shouldn't use it on a large data set.